# binary logistic regression analysis (method=ENTER) model has all beta values are statistically non-significant

Tags: regression, spss, logistic

My binary logistic regression analysis (method=ENTER) model has all beta values are statistically non-significant.

Should I include these predictors in the final binary logistic regression equation?

Comment: This is a **very** broad question about variable selection. It would be helpful if you asked a more specific question. Or, you can see one of the many other questions on this site concerning the topic of model selection - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection?sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: @Macro You are correct that the question can be interpreted broadly and therefore can be improved. However, Michael Chernick has argued, with some merit it seems to me, that this is a natural question with a natural interpretation. As such I would like to suggest it deserves a warmer welcome and more constructive guidance for eliciting the information needed to narrow it down.  (Such as--Ann--indicating the purpose of this analysis, what diagnostic plots and tests you have considered, how much data and how many variables you have, and more.) Could you and Michael cooperate in doing this?

Comment: In SPSS Method=ENTER means that all variables specified are considered simultaneously, so no variable selection. See e.g. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/output/reg_spss.htm

Comment: @Ann This question has been downvoted because it lacks critical information to elicit unchallengeable answers. Often times, negative votes are a way to indicate to the OP that the question might be improved in many ways, and they can be removed upon clarification. Some suggestions were offered to you, and I do hope you will consider them. (Also, please make sure to [register your account](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) on this site.)

Answer (score -1):

In general if a test for the regression coefficient being statistically significantly different from 0 cannot be rejected it suggests that the variable has little influence on the outcome and hence should not be included.  However, it could be that the sample size is small and hence the variance of the estimate of the regression coefficient is too large to exclude the possiblity that it is zero.  So the question then becomes how much bigger than 0 do I need the coefficient to be for me to want to include it in the model.  Then figure out how large a sample size you need to detect a difference from 0 of at least that magnitude.  If the sample size is large and all the estimates are close to 0 then exclude them and look for other predictors that might be better.  But if the sample size is small and say a 95% confidence interval for a predictor is wide enough to include 0 and your significantly high slope parameter then consider increasing the sample size before you decide.

Comment: Michael, this question is so broad (and probably a duplicate), it's hard to say whether this (or **any** answer) answers the question at all. I wish you'd use your high rep status *to help us clean up low quality, possibly duplicate, questions like this by casting close votes(or explaining why you think the close votes are misguided)* rather than just posting a response that may or may not answer the question. Since you have the expertise to tell when a question is overly broad and you are on the site so frequently, your help could really be valuable.

Comment: The shortage of action like this by high rep users (there may be a grand total of 10 users I've ever **seen** cast a close vote in my time here) is the reason that there are many low quality answers that are never removed. The moderators aren't omniscient and seem hesitant to act unilaterally on these matters.

Comment: @Macro I answered because I disagree with you.  I am not sure whether or not this duplicates other past questions but i think the question is very clear and that is why i replied.  The OP ran a logistic regression analysis with a group of variables that all turned out to have statistically insignificant coefficients.  She simply asked whether or not to exclude them all from the model based on the significance tests.  That is a simple straightforward question that does not require a complicated answer nor does it require a discussion of variable selection techniques.

Comment: Are each of them insignificant in a univariate analysis? Or, are each of them insignificant when all of them are entered at once? Who knows. Obviously those are wildly different situations and the answer to the question would depend heavily on which of these two situations you're in (or in some other situation, which is very possible). Knowing what "method=ENTER" means is probably also an important part of the question. Do you know? I sure don't. Those are just a few things that are unclear about the question.

Comment: More importantly than the unclear aspects I just pointed out is **what is the point of this endeavor**? Is it to figure out what individual predictors are important? If so, some thought about collinearity would have to be given if they are all entered into the same model. Is it to figure out whether the variables **as a group** are important? If so, we have a simple $\chi^2$ test and we're done. The point is that two rational people could interpret this question in very different ways, which is part of the definition of the *'Not a real question'* close vote reason, which is my entire point.

Comment: @Macro Certainly Method=ENTER is unclear to me and probably a lot of members of the community but the wording "has all beta values ..." was an indication that they are all included in the model.  I suppose your interpretation of insignificant when included individually is possible but I think a little farfetched.  That really would require additional explanation. Regarding what is she trying to do, I think that is clear too.  She is trying to model a binary response by logistic regression.

Comment: She has found a set of variables that she thinks might help predict the response but is stuck because none of them seem to matter. So she just wants to know what to do now.  Should she include any or all of the variables anyway or just look for others that might work?

Comment: Michael, the point is that I (+4) think the question is too vague to be useful to this site and certainly too vague for anyone (but perhaps the OP) to decree whether any given answer is "good". I suspect you can see that rational minds can differ pretty largely on what this question is asking - this is basically the definition of **'Not a real question'** and *it is a service to the community to close vote in such situations*. If you honestly believe that this question is perfectly unambiguous and can be answered in an objective way then ok but I think I've given several reasons why it is not.

Comment: Please see my blog post: [How to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/)

Comment: @macro I agree with you on this one. The topic of variable selection is broad, and is covered here often. You are to be commended for searching and finding duplicates

Comment: I was done with this until i saw Peter's comment.  This is not a question about variable selection!  It is a simple question about what to do when I do logistic regression and none of my variables are significant.  The only potential ambiguity is whether or not she tested with all variables included or not.  I think the question was clear enough to give an answer.  The other interpretation is dubious.  It is not our role on this site to be obstructionists.  When a question is clearly stated even if potentially a little ambiguous we should ask the OP for clarification and try to answer.

Comment: I understand that some questions should be closed because they don't satisfy the rules but this question is not one of them.

Comment: @Michael, one useful service community members can perform is to critically analyze the content of a question, ask for clarification and refer the OP to a relevant thread if the question is a duplicate. Your comment- **"I hope Ann will speak up to defend her question and let me know if my answer is adequate."** sums it up perfectly- your general practice appears to be to answer first and ask questions later. I have no clue why you do this but it leaves answers to ambiguous questions floating around that may be misused by users in the future, which is clearly a bad thing for the community.

Comment: @Macro If a question is very ambiguous I will ask questions first.  If I think I understand the question and have a reasonable answer I will give it.  I don't think you can point me to many instances where I have left answers that did not address the question the OP had in mind "floating around."  There will usually be discussions around such answers.  If my answer is found to be inappropriate i will take it down.  Often I am right as I think I will prove to be in this case.

Comment: @All Please move this discussion [elsewhere](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/how-can-we-best-help-to-improve-the-questions-asked-on-our-site).

Comment: no more discussion necessary